# Change every record name in a column for another one that matches a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas Dataframe where I need to replace the values in a column if they are within a list of words.

There's too many records, so I can't do it manually.

I imagine that I could use a dictionary for it, or a list, but I don't know how to implement it.

Say my dataframe is df = [[Client], [Product], [Amount]]

And that the values would be

```
Client Product    amount
John   Bubs          1
John   Supergum      1
John   Sourgum       1
John   Cherry cola   1
John   Root beer     1
```

I would like to replace all of those product names with just their category rather than their specific name

How would I go on to make it this instead

```
Client Product   Amount
   John   Bubblegum    1
   John   Bubblegum    1
   John   Bubblegum    1
   John   Beverage     1
   John   Beverage     1
```

?

Comment: Do you have the list of product words mapped to the general product type: `{'Buds: 'Bubblegun'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the dictionary with the keys as the various values you want to replace and the values of the dictionary set to the category you want to replace with.

```
list_of_gums = ['Bubs', 'Supergum', 'Sourgum']
dict_of_gums = dict.fromkeys(list_of_gums, 'Bubblegum')

dict_of_gums

{'Bubs': 'Bubblegum', 'Supergum': 'Bubblegum', 'Sourgum': 'Bubblegum'}
```

Then use `replace`

```
df.assign(Product=df.Product.replace(dict_of_gums))

  Client      Product  amount
0   John    Bubblegum       1
1   John    Bubblegum       1
2   John    Bubblegum       1
3   John  Cherry cola       1
4   John    Root beer       1
```